# How to extract the continuation data from the MatCont continuation package on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, ode

I have been using MatCont for generating continuation figures for my model ODEs. Dissatisfied with the quality of figures on MATLAB, I would like to to use another program (e.g., Gnuplot) for plotting this continuation data.

In this regard, I would like to know whether there is a way of writing the continuation data to a CSV file or similar? I tried extracting data from `.fig` figure files that were created using MATLAB but it did not work.